# Proper way to remove html code on child theme

Tags: php, functions, child-theme

I'd Like to know what is the proper way on removing this little piece of code on a child wordpres theme

```
<?php if( houzez_option('spl_con_tennant') != "" ) { ?>
                        <option value="tennant"><?php echo houzez_option('spl_con_tennant', "I'm a tennant"); ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
```

How can I remove that conditional on a child theme?

the conditional is not the functions.php file

Comment: Is it in a template file? If so, copy the template file to your child theme, and edit the copy in the child theme to remove the offending code.

Comment: Yes, it is a template file, thank you for that! but it is actually the best way to do it?

Comment: A child theme's template file will override the parent theme's file with the same filename. So yes, this is a valid way to remove the unwanted code. The only better way that I can think of will depend on if the parent theme uses a filter or an action to apply the code. If it does, you can use [`remove_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/) or [`remove_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/) to get rid of it.

Comment: Ok Thank you Pat!